# Entity Framework pull object from memory

Tags: entity-framework

I've been use entity framework, always thinks that entity framework created an abstracted layer to programmer, but i've been asking if this kind code its possible. When I create an entity and dont save db context, this object cant be pulled from the context!? Wired or I am be confused about EF!?!

```
   using (Entites db = new Entites())
            {
                tblSysState state = new tblSysState()
                                        {
                                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                            Code = "k",
                                            Description ="Just teste"
                                        };

                db.tblSysState.AddObject(state);
                Object ft = db.tblSysState.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Code.Equals("k"));


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but not with querying `ObjectSet` itself. You must access context's internal storage. Something like this should work:

```
var state = db.ObjectContext
              .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
              .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
              .Select(e => e.Entity)
              .OfType<tblSysState>()
              .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Code == "K");
```

Comment: But in this case I need know the state (Add, delete ect..) of objects you want pulled, for examaple if you want iterate all the states you will need get some objects from ObjectSet and other from context's internal storage! This is not a generic process1

Comment: You are only interested in entities in Added state because others are in the database and you can query them in the normal way. If you want to query entities in any state stored in the context use `(~EntityState.Detached)`. There is no generic process to query both local and DB data and it is by design.